# BotFramework PrivateConversationData set issue

Tags: c#, botframework

We are trying to save a simple serializable object in `PrivateConversationData` in a `Dialog` and access it from state in `MessagesController`

For some reason, after we do `Context.Done` in the dialog, we are not getting back data stored in the state

```
    public static async Task SetUserAsync<T>(IActivity activity, T botUser) where T : IBotUser
    {
        if (botUser != null)
        {
            using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity.AsMessageActivity()))
            {
                var botDataStore = scope.Resolve<IBotDataStore<BotData>>();
                var key = new AddressKey()
                {
                    BotId = activity.Recipient.Id,
                    ChannelId = activity.ChannelId,
                    UserId = activity.From.Id,
                    ConversationId = activity.Conversation.Id,
                    ServiceUrl = activity.ServiceUrl
                };

                var privateData = await botDataStore.LoadAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotPrivateConversationData, CancellationToken.None);
                privateData.SetProperty<T>(Keys.CacheBotUserKey, botUser);

                await botDataStore.SaveAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotPrivateConversationData, privateData, CancellationToken.None);
                await botDataStore.FlushAsync(key, CancellationToken.None);

            }
        }
    }
```

The dialog code is as simple as

```
    public override async Task ProcessMessageAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        BotUser user = new BotUser { UserId = "user1" };
        await StateHelper.SetUserAsync(context.Activity, user);

        var userFromState = await StateHelper.GetUserAsync<BotUser>(context.Activity);
        Debug.WriteLine("Within dialog (after set) >" + userFromState?.UserId);

        context.Done<object>(null);
    }
```

and in MessagesController.cs we are simply calling the

```
      await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new DummyDialog()).ConfigureAwait(false);

      var user = await StateHelper.GetUserAsync<BotUser>(activity);
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Within MC (end) >" + user?.UserId);
```

In this case, we get below output

```
Within dialog (after set) > user1 
Within MC (end) >
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Can you add your `GetUserAsync` implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a dialog loads, the state is loaded with it and can be accessed/saved by using the methods on the Context object. When the dialog completes, the state is persisted by the SDK.  If you create a new scope, nested within a dialog, and attempt to load/persist the state: then the dialog state will overwrite it.  To work around this, you can add a method your StateHelper that accepts an **IDialogContext**, and use that while within a Dialog.